SophosLabs Intelix API - Static File Analysis - always response BAD REQUEST
I try to use Static or Dynamic File Analysis APIs (https://api.labs.sophos.com/doc/analysis/file/static), but always get a response: BAD REQUEST
Here are my examples of request and exception:
$headers                                                                                          

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Authorization                  <Auth token>
Content-Type                   multipart/form-data

$formData 

Name                           Value
----                           -----
file                           C:\Temp\mexnixzv.gsk\outlook.exe
name                           file
filename                       outlook.exe
report_format                  json

$uri     

https://de.api.labs.sophos.com/analysis/file/static/v1/


Invoke-WebRequest -URI $uri -Method POST -Headers $headers -Form $formData -UseDefaultCredentials


$_.Exception

Response         : StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'BAD REQUEST', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
                   {
                     Connection: keep-alive
                     Date: Wed, 25 Sep 2024 07:16:05 GMT
                     Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Correlation-ID, *
                     Server: Sophos Intelix
                     Content-Security-Policy: default-src https:; script-src https: 'unsafe-inline'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline'
                     Referrer-Policy: same-origin
                     Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
                     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
                     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
                     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
                     X-Request-ID: db629807-65b5-4937-940e-0e62bd548320
                     X-Rate-Limit-Value: 30
                     X-Rate-Limit-Period: 60
                     X-Rate-Limit-Requests-Left: 29
                     X-Rate-Limit-End: 0.0
                     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
                     Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
                     Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
                     X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
                     Via: 1.1 cf058b286fa80390c08073fa68269f12.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
                     X-Amz-Cf-Pop: TXL50-P1
                     X-Amz-Cf-Id: 5vr6sgHb7DeHswIg9F9WAqwzhSesGbw8CvudJEqP7husRI2gKUKVIg==
                     Content-Type: application/json
                     Content-Length: 120
                   }
HttpRequestError : Unknown
StatusCode       : BadRequest
TargetSite       : Void ThrowTerminatingError(System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord)
Message          : Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BAD REQUEST).
Data             : {}
InnerException   :
HelpLink         :
Source           : System.Management.Automation
HResult          : -2146233088
StackTrace       :    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)

I have tried different file formats (excel, csv, jpg), different sizes (several MB and a few bytes) and different methods (PowerShell, curl, directly on the website https://api.labs.sophos.com/doc/analysis/file/static). The response is always the same: 400, BAD REQUEST
What am I doing wrong or is something broken on the API side?

I'm afraid your request is malformed. I would do the submission workflow like this:
param(
  [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$filePath,

  [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$clientId,

  [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$clientSecret,

  [Parameter(Position=3)]
  [string]$authEndPoint = 'https://api.labs.sophos.com/oauth2/token',

  [Parameter(Position=4)]
  [string]$submissionEndPoint = 'https://de.api.labs.sophos.com/analysis/file/static/v1/'
)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$resp = Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Uri $authEndPoint `
  -Method Post `
  -Headers @{
    'Content-Type'='application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    'Authorization'="Basic $([Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($clientId + ':' + $clientSecret)))"
  } `
  -Body 'grant_type=client_credentials'


$boundary = [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()

$resp = Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Uri $submissionEndPoint `
  -Method Post `
  -Headers @{
    'Content-Type'="multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary";
    'Authorization'=$resp.access_token
  } `
  -Body @"
--$boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="$([IO.Path]::GetFileName($filePath))"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

$([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filePath))

--$boundary--
"@

Write-Host $resp


Thank you for your answer here. Unfortunately, that didn't solve my problem, but it pointed me in the right direction. For whatever reason, the data sent using your script has different sha256 values ​​on both sides. But I found a good example in the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.4#example-5-submit-a-multipart-form-data-file
And here is the code that works for me:
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$filePath,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$sessionToken
)

$fieldName = 'file'
$contentType = 'application/octet-stream'

$headers = @{
    Authorization   = $sessionToken
    "Content-Type"  = "multipart/form-data"
    }
    
$FileStream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($filePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$FileHeader = [System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue]::new('form-data')
$FileHeader.Name = $fieldName
$FileHeader.FileName = Split-Path -leaf $filePath
$FileContent = [System.Net.Http.StreamContent]::new($FileStream)
$FileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = $FileHeader
$FileContent.Headers.ContentType = [System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue]::Parse($contentType)

$MultipartContent = [System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]::new()
$MultipartContent.Add($FileContent)

try {
    # send request
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $uri -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $MultipartContent
} catch {
        $statusCode = [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
}

